# Can we setFont to string?

Tags: xcode, string, fonts, nsstring

Generally in the xcode programming, we can set Font to Labels,TextFields and many more.
Well in the same way can we set font to a string(NSString)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - An `NSString` is just, well, a string. What you are looking at is the presentation of a string. And, this is separate from the actual string. In the same way that NSDate is just a date, but the way you present it is through an `NSDateFormatter`.

What you are looking for is the [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAttributedString) class.